# Firebase functions samples do not work

Tags: firebase

Recently found out what is Firebase and started studying it. I need Firebase functions for the server side of my project so I was trying to see how they work but unsuccessfully.

They have [nice "little" collection](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples) of functions examples there. I tried to start few of them like [image-maker](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/image-maker) but none of them worked for me. Image maker shows me this errors while serving the local server for it:

> !  functions: Failed to load functions source code. Ensure that you
> have the latest SDK by running npm i --save firebase-functions inside
> the functions directory.
>
> !  functions: Error from emulator.
> FirebaseError: Error parsing triggers: Cannot find module
> 'canvas-prebuilt'

I have no idea what are they talking about. I installed everything by Firebase tutorial through `firebase init`.

I have:

```
npm -v: 5.5.1
node --version: v8.9.1
```

I don't know how to check for Firebase version but I guess I have the latest one since I have just installed it. How can I fix this problem and actually try the functions? Can these functions samples be outdated? Where can I find the better ones?

Comment: The repo of samples is not the best way to learn about Cloud Functions. I recommend taking the [Cloud Functions codelab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-cloud-functions/). If you are new to JavaScript, I also recommend the [Firebase documentation for Web developers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start) and the [Firebase codelab for Web developer](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web/). They cover many basic JavaScript, Web and Firebase interactions. After those you'll be much better equipped to write code for Cloud Functions too.

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen thx for the response! I am not new to JavaScript but to all these Cloud platforms and stuff. I am used to coding in JS, JQ and other simple stuff so now I am trying to switch to npm and other apps building managers. Still, the repo of samples was listed on Firebase official website, and yet they do not work?

Comment: Did you follow the instruction on step 5 of that sample to make sure all the required modules are installed and available?  "Install dependencies locally by running: cd functions; npm install;"  The samples do work - they get used all the time.  Note that not all the samples may work in the emulator (it is limited) - definitely try to deploy them to see if they work.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson yes I did! But I still had those errors.

Comment: If you have reliable reproduction steps, please file a bug in the firebase-functions github repo.

Comment: Did you select JavaScript as the language to use when running firebase init. I spent a while with that error. I am using TypeScript and was stuck until I found in a GitHub post that you need to build the TS to JS in the function folder by running: npm run build